# When should I call nextDrawable() on a CAMetalLayer?

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

I'm using a `SCNRenderer` to render off screen and then apply some post-rendering effects to a MTLLayer which is then displayed in a CAMetalLayer.

One of the performance tips Xcode/LLVM is giving me is that I'm calling `nextDrawable()` before its needed. I'm calling it for every frame after my post-rendering effects are applied.

I'd like to know when I should be calling `nextDrawable()`?

Comment: You should call nextDrawable each time you begin rendering a new frame but make sure to run all per-frame operations that do not need a drawable resource before calling nextDrawable in order to avoid cpu stalling.

Comment: That was it. I was calling it a little bit too early which was causing LLVM to complain.

Comment: yup, it allowed me to improve my code and fixed my warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `nextDrawable` each time you begin rendering a new frame but make sure to run all per-frame operations that do not need a drawable resource before calling `nextDrawable` in order to avoid cpu stalling.